# casting from unsigned int to float

Tags: c

I have a 32 bit unsigned value that I want to convert to ieee 754 floating point.

Here are my variables:

```
unsigned int val = 0x3f800000;  
float floatVal;
```

I know that I have to do the following to be able to properly cast the uint value to the ieee 754 floating point value I expect of 1.0

```
floatVal = *((float*)&val);
```

Can anyone explain why floatVal = (float)val does not return the same result? Instead of 1.0 floatVal gets a value of 1.0653532e+009. I believe it is partially due to the fact that bits are lost during this type of typecasting whereas the bits are preserved through pointer casting but a more detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: there's also endianness. it returns 1.0 when `int` is 32 bit on a little endian machine. just tested here. but you should use memcpy to avoid violating the strict aliasing rule. you should use stdint & test endianness before attempting to convert.

Comment: In short:   `float` and `unsigned` represent values differently.    Depends what you are trying achieve. To convert the value  (e.g. so `2U` converted to `float` will have the value `2.0f`) then use `(float)val`.    To get a float that has the same binary representation (but, almost certainly different value) use `*((float *)&val)`   (bear in mind the latter ASSUMES `float` is and `unsigned`  are the same size and will not work as you describe for implementations that use non-IEEE floating point).

Comment: the cast (float)val just ignores the fact that val is encoded in IEEE format and therefore must be wrong

Comment: To reason why "gets a value of 1.0653532e+009", one should post the code, inputing the assignment and print that generated it.  A [mcve]

Answer (score 9):

1. In current C standards (C99, C11), one should [type-pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) via an union, rather than dereferencing a type-cast pointer:

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>

   uint32_t  float_bits(const float  f)
   {
       union {
           uint32_t  u;
           float     f;
       } temp;

       temp.f = f;
       return temp.u;
   }
   ```
2. Most current architectures use IEEE-754 [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) format for `float` type, but not all. If your program assumes this, it should say so in the documentation.

   I personally like to check it at compile time, and fail the compilation if my code cannot cope.
3. Most current architectures use the same byte order ([endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) for integer and float types, but not all. Again, if your program assumes this, it should say so in the documentation, or check it at compile time (using a separate test program in the same project, for example).
4. In C, the expression `(type)variable` casts the **value** of variable `variable` to type `type`. For example:

   ```
   int32_t my_truncate(float value)
   {
       return (int32_t)value;
   }
   ```

   If for example `value == 2.125`, then `my_truncate(value) == 2`.

   Similarly, casting an integer value to a floating-point type, evaluates to a floating-point value that best represents the original integer value. For example, `(float)425 == 425.0f`. (The final `f` just tells the value is of `float` type. If there is no `f` at the end of a floating-point value, its type in C is `double`.)
5. "Storage representation" refers to how values are actually stored in memory.
6. The difference between *casting* and *type-punning* is that *casting* reinterprets the value itself, but *type-punning* reinterprets how the storage representation of the value is interpreted.

   Thus, casting an integer value to a float type just yields a float that best represents the original integer value; but type-punning an integer value (of the same size as a `float`) to `float` means the storage representation of that integer value is treated as the storage representation of a float value, yielding the float value that has the same storage representation as the original integer value has.

   Similarly in the other direction. Type-punning a float to an unsigned integer type, will yield the unsigned integer (and thus bits) that has the same storage representation as the original float had. This is exactly what the `float_bits()` example function above does.
7. In C99 and later versions of the C standard, as well as in POSIXy C implementations, you can use the [`frexpf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/frexp.3.html) function to split a `float` into a normalized fraction: *x* × 2<sup>n</sup>, where either -1.0 < *x* <= -0.5f or 0.5 <= *x* < 1; and `n` is an integer exponent.

   If need be, one can use this to construct the representation of the closest value binary32 can represent, in an `uint32_t`. This can be useful on architectures that does not use IEEE 754 binary32 for `float`s.

Comment: I just learned a whole lot.  Thank you for the informative post.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!